# How to change the names in the named numbers structure in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to change the names in the Named numbers. It's harder than I thought. Any suggestions?

```
set.seed(111)
y1.predict <- rnorm(12,3,1)
y1.n1 <- c(1000, 2000, 3000, 4000,0,0,0,0,1000,4000,3000,3000)
y1.n2 <- c(0,0,0,0,1000, 2000, 3000, 4000,4000,1000,2000,2000)

y2.predict <- rnorm(16,5,1)
y2.n1 <- c(1000, 2000, 3000, 4000,0,0,0,0,1000,4000,3000,3000,1000,0,2500,4000)
y2.n2 <- c(0,0,0,0,1000, 2000, 3000, 4000,4000,1000,2000,2000,0,4000,2500,0)


df1   <- data.frame(y1.predict, n1=y1.n1, n2=y1.n2)
df2   <- data.frame(y2.predict, n1=y2.n1, n2=y2.n2)
fit.1 <- lm(y1.predict ~ n1 + n2, df1)
fit.2 <- lm(y2.predict ~ n1 + n2, df2)
#
means <- c((coef(fit.1)['(Intercept)'] + coef(fit.1)['n1'])/coef(fit.1)['(Intercept)'], (coef(fit.2)['(Intercept)'] + coef(fit.2)['n2'])/coef(fit.2)['(Intercept)'])

(Intercept) (Intercept) 
0.9999409   0.9999575

#Need to change it to
n1         n2 
0.9999409   0.9999575
```

Comment: `names(means) <- c("n1", "n2")`?

Comment: It happens to all of us, don't worry ;-)